# ClojureScript compiler throw Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: src

Tags: exception, clojure, clojurescript

I've try to compile the file using clojurescript compiler, I've followed instrcutions on [Quick-Start](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Quick-Start) but when I run:

```
java -cp cljs.jar:src clojure.main build.clj
```

I've got exception:

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: src (Nie ma takiego pliku ani katalogu), compiling:(/home/kuba/projects/jcubic/src/hello_world/build.clj:3:1)
```

the text in parenthesis is "No such file or directory".

the contents of build.clj is:

```
(require 'cljs.build.api)

(cljs.build.api/build "src" {:output-to "out/main.js"})
```

Comment: Do you have a directory called `src` in that directory?

Comment: That's your problem right there. This is where your CLJS source files go. The quickstart also has a `mkdir -p` and `touch` in there that you seem to have missed

Comment: It work when I created the directory, but I don't understand why, the source file is `src/hello_world/core.cljs`.

Comment: Followed the exact steps in the tutorial and had the same issue. Created a *src* dir under *src/hello_world* and moved the *core.cljs* there and everything works ok now.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is in location of the build file. It should be located in the project's rootdir, not underneath the src/hello_world dir. That is also from where you should invoke the build script. That way the src dir is on the right place and you do not need to create another src